# Inter-Module Functionality List in C++ - is it a bad idea?

Tags: c++, constructor, module, linker

In an old game of mine, I reached a point where keeping a header containing all possible code pieces for player "weapons", for lack of better word, forced recompilation of good 30% of the program. (If you are not into games, think about code for brushes and tools in a graphics editor, or buttons on calculator.) Then I decided that I'm not into keeping a list of what program can do, and came up with something more automatic... but it abuses global constructors.

Specifically, I made a class of double-linked list nodes that registered themselves into public class-static scope list of these nodes. Then, whenever I added a functionality of "known kind" into the program, I inserted a file-static scope list node exposing an object describing that functionality to the parts of the program which actually used it (usually a name, some virtual functions, and in some cases private variables). This means that if I want to add a new functionality of that kind to the program, I don't need to recompile any other module; the same if I want to remove it.

When I described this to my colleagues, most found this concept suspect, but I didn't receive any constructive feedback beyond some people suggesting using a non-language mechanism, like an external preprocessor. So... is it a bad practice to use setups like that, assuming you document them? Should I use it in my future programs? Maybe there's a way to explicitly ask linker to generate something like this?

Here's the header code for completeness, though I think you can answer my questions without looking at it. One could add destructor for safety, I guess... and the example usage is trivial of course.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//general header
template <class Content>
struct InterFileListNode {
     InterFileListNode * next, * prev;
     Content content;
     static InterFileListNode * first, * last;
     InterFileListNode(const Content & t) : content(t) {
         if (last==0) {
              first = last = this;
              next = prev = 0;
         } else {
              prev = last;
              next = 0;
              last->next = this;
              last = this;
         }
     }
};
template <class Content>
InterFileListNode<Content> * InterFileListNode<Content>::first = 0;
template <class Content>
InterFileListNode<Content> * InterFileListNode<Content>::last = 0;

//header for functionality type
struct Functionality {
    const char * name;
    void (*funcptr)(void);
};
typedef InterFileListNode<Functionality *> FunctionalityNode;
//module with functionality
void nothing() {}
static Functionality foobar = {"do nothing", nothing};
static FunctionalityNode node(&foobar);
//module using functionality (usually a toolbox, but here for simplicity not):
int main() {
    FunctionalityNode * ptr = FunctionalityNode::first;
    while (ptr != 0) {
        cout << ptr->content->name << endl;
        (ptr->content->funcptr)();
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow: if you had a `class A` used in `foo.cpp`, how would that work out?

Comment: I Note that this kind of question is perhaps better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com or https://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @didierc This is more about the algorithm than the code, so I purposefully ignored the Code Review. Investigating the Programmers site though.

Comment: The thing is: stackoverflow.com is more about proper working code than good practice (IMHO), as this is subject to debate. People here will help you fix bug, or explain something leading to unexpected behaviour (from OP standpoint), but will frown upon opinion based answers (though it varies depending on the tag "subgroup" moderating trends